# Why isn't this VHDL falling edge detector reliable?

Tags: fpga

I'm trying to write an RS232 decoder for my Mojo v3 (Spartan 6 XC6SLX9). I know I can find existing libraries to do this - I'd just like to do it myself. As part of the decoding, I need to detect the high-to-low transition for the start bit.

Many sources, such as fpgacenter's edge detector and Pong Chu's FPGA Prototyping by VHDL Examples book, recommend something like this:

```
architecture arch of edge_detector is
    signal last: std_logic;
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            last <= signal_in;
        end if;
    end process;

    output <= (not signal_in) and last; 
end arch;
```

I haven't found that to be a reliable detector of falling edges. In particular, it appears to miss falling edges when the FPGA sees the edge near the rising edge of the clock:

[image: missed edge]

SLOW is an edge detector that uses two registers to do the detection. Whereas FAST will fire in the same clock cycle as the falling edge, SLOW fires in the next cycle. BAD goes high when it sees SLOW fire without a corresponding tick from FAST. RAW_RX is direct from the FTDI USB-to-Serial transceiver, bypassing the FPGA; RX is that same signal as seen from inside the FPGA (and routed back out, like FAST, SLOW, etc). CLK is a 50MHz clock.

The same falling edge detector properly fires when it sees a high-to-low transition during the clock cycle:

[image: found edge]

That successful detection also illustrates why I've called SLOW slow.

What am I doing wrong? Is this detector expected to work when transitions coincide with clock rising edges?

Comment: I'm assuming "signal_in" is the input pin? Your "FAST" detection shouldn't work for the reason Trevor stated, however since purely combinatorial operations aren't timed by the tools it appears you are able to have a scenario where "not signal_in" is updated after to "last" is calculated

Comment: A synchroniser on the input would help to catch metastable states.

Comment: @ks0ze yes, signal_in is the input pin.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I'm a hobbyist, new to both VHDL and FPGAs, and don't understand your comment. Could you give me a pointer to something that explains what a synchronizer would be in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"signal_in" is not timed by the development tools until it is brought into a clocked element (i.e. register). Because of this there is nothing that says "not signal_in" has to be valid before/after "last" is updated.

Therefore, when "last" and "not signal_in" are ANDed together there is essentially a race condition, where the final result can vary (between builds due to routing and between FPGAs due to variations in the specific fabric). This is why signals should always be brought onto a clock before being used in calculations.

[image: VHDL Design]

Answer (score 1):

You are grabbing last in the same cycle as your test, Signal_In can change between instructions.

It should be more like this.

```
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        output <= (not signal_in) and last; 
        last <= signal_in;
    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks. It causes FAST to degrade to the same response time as SLOW. But I guess that makes since because the FAST algorithm doesn't really have time to signal anything when the edge is close enough to the transition?

Comment: @simmonmt Don't forget to accept the answer then. Or you will  consume other people time.